# Access a HashMap from a separate jar

Tags: java, jar, import, hashmap, public

So I have this code in `JarFile1.jar`:

`public static HashMap<String, Double[]> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Double[]>();`

How would I access that variable in a separate `JarFile2.jar` using `import`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put getter and setter to that var in jar1File:

```
class MyClass {
public HashMap<String, Double[]> getMyHashMap() {
    return myHashMap;
}
public void setMyHashMap(HashMap<String, Double[]> myHashMap) {
    this.myHashMap = myHashMap;
}
}
```

Once you are in jarFile2 just you the Class name, Because this is static member.

```
class MyClassJar2 {
    public MyClassJar2() {
         MyClass.getMyHashMap();
    }
}
```

So when you will import you can access that var

Hope that help :)

Comment: why would you need getters and setters if the variable is public static. You can access it like MyClass.myHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that doesn't sound like a good practice at all. It's not a good idea to allow access to an atribute of an object like a Map (you could clutter the data easily and without noticing).

If you want to access data from another class, you could implement a public method like `public double[] getData(String key)` and importing it in the other jar. Also, note that you need to add the first jar to the classpath while executing the second one.